# Is System.CommandLine F#-friendly?

Tags: f#, command-line-interface, system.commandline

For F# apps, I've traditionally used different functional-friendly command line parsers like [Argu](https://github.com/fsprojects/Argu) and [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline#f-examples).

Now that Microsoft has come up with [System.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/) (with potentially brings better support and documentation), is it usable from F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functional-friendliness is subjective, but I found the API rather convenient for F#:

```ml
open System.CommandLine
open System.CommandLine.Invocation

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let option1 = Option<string> "--option1"
    let option2 = Option<string> "--option2"
    let option3 = Option<string> "--option3"
    let option4 = Option<string> "--option4"

    let command1 = Command "command 1"
    command1.AddOption option1
    command1.AddOption option2
    command1.Handler <- CommandHandler.Create (fun option1 option2 -> Operation1.run option1 option2)

    let command2 = Command "command 2"
    command2.AddOption option3
    command2.AddOption option4
    command2.Handler <- CommandHandler.Create (fun option3 option4 -> Operation1.run option3 option4)

    let rootCommand = RootCommand "My tool."
    rootCommand.AddCommand command1
    rootCommand.AddCommand command2

    rootCommand.Invoke argv
```

To make code more fun, some trivial helpers can help:

```ml
open System.CommandLine

let addCommand subCommand (command: Command) =
    command.AddCommand subCommand
    command

let addOption option (command: Command) =
    command.AddOption option
    command

let setHandler handler (command: Command) =
    command.Handler <- handler
    command
```

To be used like:

```ml
open System.CommandLine
open System.CommandLine.Invocation

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let option1 = Option<string> "--option1"
    let option2 = Option<string> "--option2"
    let option3 = Option<string> "--option3"
    let option4 = Option<string> "--option4"

    let command1 =
        Command "command 1"
        |> addOption option1
        |> addOption option2
        |> setHandler (CommandHandler.Create (fun option1 option2 -> Operation1.run option1 option2))

    let command2 =
        Command "command 2"
        |> addOption option3
        |> addOption option4
        |> setHandler (CommandHandler.Create (fun option3 option4 -> Operation2.run option3 option4))

    let rootCommand =
        RootCommand "My tool."
        |> addCommand command1
        |> addCommand command2

    rootCommand.Invoke argv
```

This also seems to be a dedicated [library](https://github.com/JordanMarr/FSharp.SystemCommandLine) for having `System.CommandLine` in the F# way.

F# was likely taken into mind during the library design, although there are some caveats, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/issues/941#issuecomment-647153751) for command handler binding.

In general, the library is still in the preview so the API might substantially change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I found psfinaki's answer very helpful, and have updated it based on changes that have come to System.CommandLine.

```
open System.CommandLine
open System.CommandLine.Invocation

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    
    let command1 = Command "command1"
    command1.AddAlias("com1")
    
    let exampleHandler () = printf "You ran command 1"
    
    command1.SetHandler(exampleHandler)

    let command2 = Command "command2"
    
    let argument1 = Argument<string> "nameArg"
    command2.AddArgument(argument1)
    
    let exampleHandler2 (arg) = printf $"You ran command 2, with arg {arg}"
    
    command2.SetHandler(exampleHandler2, argument1)

    let rootCommand = RootCommand "My tool."
    rootCommand.AddCommand command1
    rootCommand.AddCommand command2

    rootCommand.Invoke argv
```